# iOS - Keyboard Extension word prediction with from a .txt file

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm creating a Keyboard extension to show prediction from a .txt file.

txt file contains almost 350000 words.

Right now i'm fetching all the words from file and storing it in an Array of String and then filter that array.

```
extension String {
var lines: [String] {
      var result: [String] = []
      enumerateLines { line, _ in result.append(line) }
      return result
  }
}


autoreleasepool{
    if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Words", withExtension: "txt") {
        if let words = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8) {
            arrayWords += words.lines
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it's using too much memory(65-70 MB). CPU usage reaches almost 180% at launch and is always above 90% whenever i type a character.

Is there any way to reduce memory and CPU usage?

Comment: What does a guy named 'lines' come from?

Comment: Sorry forgot add, will update the code

Comment: this SO answer could be very useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581832/how-to-filter-large-array-in-ios-swift-2-for-uisearchbar

Comment: you may also want to look at the "Trie" data structure, and its many swift implementations (on github in particular) to do auto completion/prediction.